# Select the row with maximum/minimum value in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, max, aggregate-functions

According to [the docs](https://sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#maxggunc), common sense and some manuals on common SQL the  `max` function returns only maximum value. So the correct way to select the row(s) with the maximum value is a subquery:

```
select * from `table` where `a`=(select max(`a`) from `table`);
```

It's inefficient. Are there something like `argmax` in SQLite?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#bareagg), SQLite allows to select the entire row with `max()`:

```
SELECT *, max(a) FROM MyTable;
```

(This is supported since version [3.7.11](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_7_11.html).)

Comment: When using this with Android Room, you will get a warning for the unused `MAX(...)` column during building; and most importantly, it looks like the DAO does not return `null` if there are no rows in the table, but instead returns an object with all default field values.

Comment: Yes, I confirm this should not be used with Room if there is a chance that no row is found. If that happens, it returns a row of NULL columns, which generates an exception for columns not supporting null values. Using the inner join is safer and cleaner as it doesn't add the MAX column.

Answer (score 4):

It is. Just use

```
select max(`a`), * from `table`;
```

if a single row is enough for you. The rest of values will belong to the row from which the maximum value is taken.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used SQLite much, but I think

```
select l.* from `table` l join (select * from `table` order by `a` desc limit 1) r on l.`a` = r.`a`;
```

should give good performance. Having an index on `a` should make it really fast. Without an index it should result in two sequence scans of `table`.

Answer (score 0):

To get more than one rows, your solution is absolutely *not* inefficient -- assuming you indexed column `a`, which you probably should in this situation.

```
create index myidx on mytable(a);
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check the below query for **`max`** and **`min`** value for your choice row.

The query for **`max`** value in a row:

```
SELECT max(timestamp) FROM tableName
```

The query for **`min`** value in a row:

```
SELECT min(timestamp) FROM tableName
```

**Note**: timestamp is row name in the table. You can use where you want to apply.